# virtualenv uses Python 2.6 instead of 2.7

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv and installed some packages with pip.  I want to use Python 2.7, which is the default version on my system.
The env's lib folder contains a folder for Python 2.6, not 2.7.  Why is it not using 2.7, and how can I correct it?

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6

$ virtualenv flask

flask/
    bin/
    app/
    lib/
       Python2.6/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find where python2.7 is, then tell virtualenv to use that binary.

```
$ which python2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
$ virtualenv -p $(which python2.7) flask
```

---

For example, on Ubuntu, install virtualenv with `sudo apt-get install virtualenv`. Create an env with `virtualenv vpy`.  This creates a `vpy` directory.  Next run `. ./vpy/bin/activate` to activate the env.  Install packages with pip like `pip install flask`.

Every time you start a new shell, you must activate the env again with `. ./vpy/bin/activate`.